# ADB, Samsung Epic 4G, Windows 7, Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adb, galaxy

I have searched a lot on the forums, and most similar questions seem to be primarily Windows XP issues.

I am using the latest versions of Eclipse, Jdk, Android Sdk, and Adt.  I am trying to debug on my phone, a Samsung Galaxy 4G/SII.

I downloaded drivers from samsung, and they seem to install ok, but my computer blue screens right as the installer finishes.

Adb does not see the phone, and it also doesnt see my wifes HTC Evo shift.  Neither device is recognized by adb from a command line, and neither will show up in the Android device chooser.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What type of OS are you using? If you are using Windows XP which is 32-bit OS, there is little or nothing you can do as it doesnt contain all necessary libraries needed to run the current or recent SDK tools. You might have to install some patches to make it work, consult XP documentation manual for more solution on running SDK tools. I have it on my Windows 7, and it is working perfectly. I only need to connect my Samsung phone to my computer, and I am able to debug directly. I would rather advise that you upgrade your OS.